# R statistics programming : using magrittr piping to pass 2 parameters to function

Tags: r, magrittr

I am using magrittr, and was able to pass one variable to an R function via pipes from magrittr, and also pick which parameter to place where in the situation of multivariable function : F(x,y,z,...)

But i want to pass 2 parameters at the same time.

For example, i will using Select function from dplyr and pass in tableName and ColumnName:

I thought i could do it like this:

> > tableName %>% ColumnName %>% select(.,.)

But this did not work.
Hope someone can help me on this.

EDIT :

Some below are saying that this is a duplicate of a link provided by others.
But based on the algebra structure of the magrittr definition of Pipe for multivariable functions, it should be "doable" just based on the algebra definition of the pipe function.

The link provided by others, goes beyond the base definition and employs other external functions and or libraries to try to achieve passing multiple parameter to the function.

I am looking for a solution, IF POSSIBLE, just using the *magrittr* library and other base operations.

So this is the restriction that is placed on this problem.

In most of my university courses in math and computer science we were restricted to use only those things taught in the course. So when I said I am using *dplyr* and *magrittr*, that should imply that those are the only things one is permitted to use, so its under this constraint.

Hope this clarifies the scope of possible solutions here.

And if it's not possible to do this via just these libraries I want someone to tell me that it cannot be done.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198522/discussion-on-question-by-palu-r-statistics-programming-using-magrittr-piping).

Comment: Hi Samuel, i got to the chat room based on your link, i can see everything, but i can't post in it. At the bottom of the page it says i have to be logged in, but I am logged in. I tried it in one browser, and i got an error message saying there are problems with Stackoverflow at the moment. In this current browser, firefox, i get the same message telling me i have to be logged in when i am logged in, but don't get any error messages, but i keep going in circles from the chat room i click login, and i get to my regular page on stackoverflow where i am still logged in. So i am going in circles

Comment: This was a result of the user merge. Please use the contact us link at the bottom of the site to contact the developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need a little more detail about exactly what you want, but as I understand the problem, I think one solution might be:

`list(x = tableName, y = "ColumnName") %>% {select(eval(.$x),.$y) }`

This is just a modification of the code linked in the chat. The issue with other implementations is that the first and second inputs to `select()` must be of specific (and different) types. So just plugging in two strings or two objects won't work.

In the same spirit, you can also use either:

`list(x = "tableName", y = "ColumnName") %>% { select(get(.$x),.$y) }`

or

`list(tableName, "ColumnName") %>% do.call("select", .)`.

Note, however, that all of these functions (i.e., `get()`, `eval()`, and `do.call()`) have an environment specification in them and could result in errors if improperly specified. They work just fine in these examples because everything is happening in the global environment, but that might change if they were, e.g., called in a function.

Comment: Hi Arwood, this is exactly what i was looking for. So with the select() function of dplyr, one has to be more careful in terms of how the parameters are passed in, in terms of data types.

Comment: I tried your code out for the table name and column i am using, and your code works! I will give your reply as the answer to this question. But another suggested using another function called 'do.call()', just wondering if you know if you can do this with the 'do.call()' function as well.

Comment: Yes you can do this with `do.call()` using `list(tableName, "ColumnName") %>% do.call("select", .)`. Note that for all of these you need to be aware of the environment in which the evaluation is being performed or things could go wrong. I'll update my answer to provide a little more context.

Comment: Hi Arwood, thanks for your efforts on this, i really appreciate it. I will give this a try to see if it works, and i will get you some feedback. Thanks for the warning about issues with this method.

Comment: Hi arwood, i tried it by just replacing tableName with my specific table and the specific column name, and It Worked! So the issue was having, i was doing things in a uniform way, meaning either both tableName and ColumnName in the list() was either quoted or unquoted, i tried these 2 variations, so i would not have thought of one being unquoted with other would be quoted. So its just trying to understand how the syntax rules for these functions work. Thanks so much again, appreciate it a lot.

Comment: In the future, just pay attention to what inputs are required by the final function (e.g., `select()`) and you can adapt these methods to produce that input. You can always inspect the documentation for a function (using, e.g., `?select()`) - in most cases, you will be able to use that to determine what inputs are required.